# Can I just show the list of found tokens in RapidMiner?

Tags: tokenize, rapidminer

I made a process which reads a file, then makes document of it, then tokenizes it by regular expressions. Preview mode of tokenizer highlights found patterns correctly.

Now can I just get a list of found patterns on my screen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the Tokenize operator with Process Documents and place the Tokenize operator inside it. The word list output of this represents the tokens.

Comment: Thank! Looks like regular expression worked as separator. Is this by design? I would like to collect regular expression matches. Is this possible?

Comment: The regular expression defines delimiters between tokens. I suppose (with some ninja regex) you could negate it so the tokens became the delimiters.

Comment: WHY it supports only delimiters? What is an idea of it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do but if it helps, you can use the "Filter Documents (by content)" to look for specific items.